# How to change row width?

Tags: width

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[\displaystyle \lim_{x \to+\infty}f(x)=\frac{\lim_{x \to+\infty}1+\lim_{x \to+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}+\lim_{x \to+\infty}\frac{3}{x^3}+\lim_{x \to+\infty}\frac{1}{x^4}}{\lim_{x \to+\infty}-4+\lim_{x \to+\infty}\frac{5}{x^3}-\lim_{x \to+\infty}\frac{1}{x^4}}=-\frac{1}{4}
\end{document}
```

[image]

how can I increase the row width? I want **x->infty** below the lim sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `\limits` before each subscript:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}

    \begin{document}

    \[\lim\limits_{x \to+\infty}f(x)=\frac{\lim\limits_{x \to+\infty}1+\lim\limits_{x \to+\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\lim\limits_{x \to+\infty}\dfrac{3}{x^3}+\lim\limits_{x \to+\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^4}}{\lim\limits_{x \to+\infty}-4+\lim\limits_{x \to+\infty}\dfrac{5}{x^3}-\lim\limits_{x \to+\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^4}}=-\frac{1}{4} \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: you're right (tested). Done, mylord! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

To save yourself from having to type `\lim\limits` 7 or more times, I suggest you create a macro -- called `\ddfrac` in the code below -- that automatically renders the contents of the numerator and denominator of a `\frac` expression in `\displaystyle` math mode. To cut down on the visual clutter, I would also replace all 8 instances of `+\infty` with "just" `\infty`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts}  % amsfonts is loaded automatically by amssymb
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}

\begin{document}
\[
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)
=\ddfrac{\lim_{x\to\infty}1+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}
        +\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3}{x^3}+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^4}}%
        {\lim_{x\to\infty}-4+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{5}{x^3}
        -\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^4}}
=-\frac{1}{4}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: i appreciate this answer, i sometimes have trouble with correct bracketing numbers when the syntax is too long.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have decided to put limits underneath the `\lim`, you might also want to change format of this limit and normalise spacing between terms by setting custom values to `\thinmuskip` and `\medmuskip`.**Note** to keep those settings within a group so they won't affect the rest of the document.

Another problem is the limits are long. For this particular case, I'd use array instead of the `\limits` to: have more control over a gap between limits and `\lim`; align limits with operator `\lim`.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xlim}{e_}{%
  \mathop{
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      \lim \\[\dimexpr7pt-\normalbaselineskip]
      \mathrlap{\scriptstyle#1} \\[\dimexpr0.2\normalbaselineskip-4pt]
    \end{array}}}


\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \thinmuskip=8mu plus 6mu minus 9mu
  \medmuskip=14mu plus 6mu minus 8mu
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}
  \[
    \lim\limits_{\rule{0pt}{5pt}\mathclap{x\to+\infty}} f(x)
    = \frac{
      \;
        \xlim_{x\to+\infty} 1
        + \xlim_{x\to+\infty} 1/x^2
        + \xlim_{x\to+\infty} 3/x^3
        + \xlim_{x\to+\infty} 1/x^4
      \;
    }{
      \xlim_{x\to+\infty} -4
      + \xlim_{x\to+\infty} 5/x^3
      - \xlim_{x\to+\infty} 1/x^4
    } = -\frac{1}{4}
  \]
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should add MWE, which produce showed equation ...

Comment: @Zarko I added the missing code. Thank you for the ping. I would probably leave it as is.